# Robo 3T MongoDB Not primary

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to run an aggregate query which needs to output some documents to another collection on the same database. Th problem I'm currently having is that without the $out stage, the query works, but when I put in the $out stage, it just gives me the following error:
[image]

This is the query:

```
use catchem
db.quests.aggregate([
    { $match: { distanceFromStage: { $lte: 50 }}},
    { $sort: { stageId: 1, questId: 1, distanceFromStage: -1}},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$stageId",
        measurements: {$push: {
            questId: "$questId",
            stageId: "$stageId",
            hartslag: "$hartslag",
            decibelmeter: "$decibelmeter",
            distanceFromStage: "$distanceFromStage",
            stageLoc: "$stageLoc"
        }}
    }},
    { $unwind: "$measurements"},
    { $bucket: {
        groupBy: "$measurements.distanceFromStage",
        boundaries: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        output: { 
            stagesByDistance: { $push: {      
                questId: "$measurements.questId",
                stageId: "$measurements.stageId",
                hartslag: "$measurements.hartslag",
                decibelmeter: "$measurements.decibelmeter",
                distanceFromStage: "$measurements.distanceFromStage",
                stageLoc: "$measurements.stageLoc"
            }}
        }
    }},
    { $unwind:"$stagesByDistance"},
    { $group: {
        _id: {stageId: "$stagesByDistance.stageId", distance: "$_id"},
        avgBpm: {$avg: "$stagesByDistance.hartslag"},
        avgDb: {$avg: "$stagesByDistance.decibelmeter"},
    }},
    { $sort: {_id: 1}},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id.stageId",
        avgs: { $push: {
            distance: "$_id.distance",
            avgBpm: "$avgBpm",
            avgDb: "$avgDb"
        }}
    }},
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        stageId: "$_id",
        avgBpm10: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgBpm", 0]},
        avgBpm20: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgBpm", 1]},
        avgBpm30: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgBpm", 2]},
        avgBpm40: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgBpm", 3]},
        avgBpm50: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgBpm", 4]},
        avgDb10: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgDb", 0]},
        avgDb20: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgDb", 1]},
        avgDb30: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgDb", 2]},
        avgDb40: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgDb", 3]},
        avgDb50: {$arrayElemAt: ["$avgs.avgDb", 4]}
    }},
    { $sort: { stageId: 1}},
    { $out: "heatmaps" }
],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

This is the sh.status(true):

```
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5bd483c5736ad7af3ebb1b9b")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "Catchem_RS1",  "host" : "Catchem_RS1/localhost:27030,localhost:27031,localhost:27032",  "state" : 1 }
    {  "_id" : "Catchem_RS2",  "host" : "Catchem_RS2/localhost:27033,localhost:27034,localhost:27035",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
    {  "_id" : "Laptop-Cedric:27039",  "advisoryHostFQDNs" : [ ],  "mongoVersion" : "4.0.3",  "ping" : ISODate("2018-10-31T16:49:16.455Z"),  "up" : NumberLong(3920),  "waiting" : true }
 autosplit:
    Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  2
    Last reported error:  Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set Catchem_RS2
    Time of Reported error:  Mon Oct 29 2018 17:13:28 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
        No recent migrations
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "catchem",  "primary" : "Catchem_RS1",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : BinData(4,"blaviOp/SLC+zhJTT74pbg=="),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
        catchem.quests
            shard key: { "questId" : 1 }
            unique: false
            balancing: true
            chunks:
                undefined   undefined
                undefined   undefined
            { "questId" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "questId" : 130 } on : Catchem_RS2 Timestamp(2, 0) 
            { "questId" : 130 } -->> { "questId" : 259 } on : Catchem_RS2 Timestamp(3, 0) 
            { "questId" : 259 } -->> { "questId" : 388 } on : Catchem_RS2 Timestamp(4, 0) 
            { "questId" : 388 } -->> { "questId" : 517 } on : Catchem_RS2 Timestamp(5, 0) 
            { "questId" : 517 } -->> { "questId" : 646 } on : Catchem_RS2 Timestamp(6, 0) 
            { "questId" : 646 } -->> { "questId" : 775 } on : Catchem_RS2 Timestamp(7, 0) 
            { "questId" : 775 } -->> { "questId" : 905 } on : Catchem_RS2 Timestamp(8, 0) 
            { "questId" : 905 } -->> { "questId" : 1034 } on : Catchem_RS2 Timestamp(9, 0) 
            { "questId" : 1034 } -->> { "questId" : 1163 } on : Catchem_RS1 Timestamp(9, 1) 
            { "questId" : 1163 } -->> { "questId" : 1292 } on : Catchem_RS1 Timestamp(1, 9) 
            { "questId" : 1292 } -->> { "questId" : 1421 } on : Catchem_RS1 Timestamp(1, 10) 
            { "questId" : 1421 } -->> { "questId" : 1550 } on : Catchem_RS1 Timestamp(1, 11) 
            { "questId" : 1550 } -->> { "questId" : 1680 } on : Catchem_RS1 Timestamp(1, 12) 
            { "questId" : 1680 } -->> { "questId" : 1809 } on : Catchem_RS1 Timestamp(1, 13) 
            { "questId" : 1809 } -->> { "questId" : 1938 } on : Catchem_RS1 Timestamp(1, 14) 
            { "questId" : 1938 } -->> { "questId" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : Catchem_RS1 Timestamp(1, 15)
```

localhost:27030, localhost:27033 are the primary nodes for the corresponding replicasets.

Answer (score 0):

- $out cannot be used in a secondary node.
- A sharded collection cannot be specified as the output collection.

Running the aggregation through the `mongos` instead of pointing to a secondary node should solve the problem.

Comment: The aggregation ran on the mongos, the routing service Robo 3T is connected to. That's the issue. It should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the way connections are managed by Robo3T. I recommend to open an issue on their [github repo](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues).  

Using the direct connection fails with the reported error.  

As a workaround you can connect using a replica set connection on Robo 3T:  

In my test:
Type: Replica Set
Members: localhost:27017 localhost:27018 localhost:27019 localhost:27020
SetName: shard01